# Short story in which a planet's disc-like, flying lifeforms are proven intelligent when they arrange themselves in a star-shape on Christmas

Tags: story-identification

Humans are colonizing a planet in order to extract its natural resources, but this is forbidden on planets with intelligent life, and there is debate over whether this planet's disc-shaped, multicolored, winged creatures are indeed intelligent.  They are proven to be so when a group of them, aflight, arrange themselves in the shape of a star -- or if not a star, then the word "NOEL" or something similarly festive --  on Christmas.

I read this around 1978-1981, perhaps in Omni magazine.

Comment: Should you return, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

[The Heavenly Host](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/a/isaac-asimov/heavenly-host.htm) by Isaac Asimov.

It contains [wheel-like creatures](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/isaac-asimov/heavenly-host/):

> "The little Wheel sparkled with rapid white flashes and there was the sound of laughter in Jonathan's head."

The protagonist wants to prove that the Wheels are intelligent to protect the planet from land developers. The Wheels prove that they are intelligent by putting on a Christmas light show.

The story was [originally published in *Boy's Life* and later turned into a book](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book167.html).